# Query regarding svn log command line

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN on windows, with the command-line `svn.exe`.

I am struggling to get latest `svn log` message for a particular text in log Message.
I am using the below command to get all the log messages for a particular text.

```
svn log --search="text"
```

I get a list of messages having that "text". But from this list, I just want the latest one. How can I get that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `-l 1` to your command like this:

```
svn log -l 1 --search="text"
```

The `-l` flag is the shorter version of `--limit`:

> --limit (-l) NUM
>
> Shows only the first NUM log messages.

By `first NUM log messages` it means the first it hits in order from newest -> oldest.

You view some documenation on the `svn log` command **[here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html)**.

---

The above doesn't actually work in this case as per @bahrep's answer however as this doesn't appear to be possible using `svn.exe` only. I have created a python script that does it:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import subprocess
import sys

# Change the below to your url and search string
url = "http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/spamassassin/trunk"
search_term = "160"

# Run the svn log command and get the results as xml
args = ["svn", "log",'--search="{0}"'.format(search_term), url, "--xml"]
svn_out = subprocess.check_output(" ".join(args))
svn_xml = ET.fromstring(svn_out)

try:
    # Get the latest log by revision number
    latest_log = max(svn_xml, key=lambda x : int(x.attrib["revision"]))
except ValueError:
    sys.exit("No Results Found")  # Empty svn_xml would indicate no results.

# Print log author and message
author = latest_log.find("author").text
msg = latest_log.find("msg").text
print "{0} : {1}".format(author, msg)
```

Which returns for me using `python 2.7` in Windows:

```
python .\svn_redemption.py
spamassassin_role : updated scores for revision 1607021 active rules added since last mass-check
```

Basically it gets the `xml` results from the the command line output, then gets the highest revision as the result.

You'll need to change the `url` and the `search_term` variables to the ones you want, but it should work.

Comment: It is not able to find anything. `svn log --search="0072" <SVN-URL>` gives 3 set of rows in the result. But when I use `svn log --search="0072" -l 1 <SVN_URL>`, it doesnt return any row.

Comment: It appears that `-l 1` option limits the search to 1 last revision. It looks useless in such case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not possible with just `svn.exe` command-line client.

**Unactual part below, see updated @Noelkd's answer!**

@Noelkd's answer is not correct, as far as I can see now. Using `-l 1` option limits the search query's range, not the output it produces.